# Can we install Sqoop, Hive & MySQL in Name Node (Master) of a Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I have a multi-node Hadoop cluster as 1 master and 2 Slaves.

- i want to try import from MySQL and load in HDFS.
- i want to have Hive to write hive queries on HDFS.

to perform above task, can I install Hive, Sqoop, MySQL on Name-Node (Master) of my Hadoop cluster?

or is it mandatory to have Edgenode?

Answer (score 1):

Having an edgenode is a network architectural pattern in a Hadoop cluster, not a hard-requirement for anything. Edgenodes only run client applications, not run server processes (other than `sshd`)

Ideally, MySQL runs separate from Hadoop servers. Your NameNode(s) should also be independent servers with a large amount of reserve RAM for cluster growth.

You can run sqoop completely outside of the cluster, even. It only needs network access to HDFS, YARN, and the database (it is basically a wrapper around Mapreduce and JDBC clients). By the way, Sqoop is a retired Apache project, so I suggest finding an alternative solution, such as Spark (or a project called [Spooq](https://github.com/supermariolabs/spooq)).

Comment: Oh okay understood. But still will it be fine to install client applications on name node just for poc. Ya?

Comment: Ya ya. For a POC, you can have a single-node install of everything.